# Indexing into channel data (numpy arrays) using OpenCV python bindings

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to do a channel compare on two numpy arrays generated from the OpenCV (2.3.1) Python bindings. So, I have a mask (array/image/channel) of shape (x, y) that I want to compare against each channel of an RGB array/image of shape (x,y,3).

Having halfway wrapped my head around numpy's slicing, I can get closer to what I want:

```
channel = ndarr[...,i:i+1]     #where i is the channel I want
```

... but this returns an ndarray of shape (x,y,1) rather than the (x,y) I need. Is there an elegant way to do this in a single slicing operation. Failing that, what is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a slice, but rather a simple index:

```
channel = ndarr[..., i]
```

This actually behaves the same as slicing and indexing normal Python lists.  Using a slice of length one results in a sublist, and using simple indexing results in the element being returned:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[2:3]
[2]
>>> a[2]
2
```